# Wordpress not handling dynamic requests

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried migrating my wordpress from xampp to a web server. Changed the site fields in the sql database, exported the database, updated wp-config, set permissions and uploaded the page.

The front page loads fine and I can access the admin page through /wp-admin (where everything functions) but any page request that isn't an actual file (like /admin) results in error 500.

I'm not sure how those work in PHP anyways. Is there some configuration  I missed maybe? I also have access to **php.ini** if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since I moved the deployment from /wordpress/ to htdocs root, I also had to edit the .htaccess file to change rewrite path.